# jQuery. Navigating from a removed element

Tags: jquery

Say I have:

```
<div>
    <input type="button">
</div>
<img src="path/to/img.jpg">
```

And I want to hide the button and then hide the image, I could do this with:

```
$('input[type="button"]').hide().parent().next('img').hide();
```

When I want to remove the element, how can I then navigate to the image in a similar fashion?

```
$('input[type="button"]').remove().parent().next('img').hide();
```

Doesn't do the trick.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8xN2/

TLDR: Is it possible to continue to navigate the DOM from the current position after removing an element?

Comment: TLDR: No. The element was removed from the DOM. It doesn't have a parent anymore.

Comment: What's wrong with caching the element, hiding the img, then removing the element? Had your selector been more simple, you could have just used `.addBack`, but sequence of those feels awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the image in a local variable and then use it for whatever you want.

```
var image = $(this).parent().next('img');
    $(this).remove();
    image.hide();
```

Check the updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f8xN2/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can save parent first: `var divParent = $('input[type="button"]').parent();` and then remove the element and access image with `divParent.next('img').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the second element before removing the first one:

```
var second = $('input[type="button"]').parent().next('img');
$('input[type="button"]').remove();
second.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain after removing an element

do like that

```
        $(function(){
        $('#ex1').click(function(){
            $(this).hide().parent().next('img').hide();
        });
        $('#ex2').click(function(){
            //hide image
            $(this).parent().next('img').hide();
            //then remove
            $(this).remove()
        });
    })
```